# not matching a set number of characters in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following expression

```
diff_pr_EUR-44_cordex_rcp45_mon_ave_2048-2060_minus_2005-2017_mon10_ave1_withsd.nc
```

I would like to use `regex` to extract and generate the following string

```
rcp45_mon10
```

I have tried this so far with  the online [regex tester](https://regexr.com/)

```
rcp\d\d[^.]+mon\d+
```

Which extracts more than what I need...

```
rcp45_mon_ave_2048-2060_minus_2005-2017_mon10
```

How can I get regex to skip subsequent characters until it reaches the `mon10` part?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` here:

```
>>> s = 'diff_pr_EUR-44_cordex_rcp45_mon_ave_2048-2060_minus_2005-2017_mon10_ave1_withsd.nc'
>>> print (re.sub(r'^.*?(rcp\d+).*(_mon\d+).*', r'\1\2', s))
rcp45_mon10
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/339foc/1)

**Details:**

- `^.*?`: Match 0 or of any characters at the start (lazy)
- `(rcp\d+)`: Match and capture `rcp` followed by 1+ digits in group #1
- `.*`: Match 0 or of any characters (greedy)
- `(_mon\d+)`: Match and capture `_mon` followed by 1+ digits in group #2
- `.*`: Match anything till the end
- `r'\1\2'`: Replace string by back-references of group #1 and group #2

Answer (score 2):

You can match using two matching groups, and `join`:

```
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'(rcp\d{2}).*?(\_mon\d{2})', s)[0])
'rcp45_mon10'
```

Comment: You don't need to make `.*` lazy, and you don't need to escape the `_`.